# Would a cold glass, put on a wet surface, break more easily when you pour hot water in it?

Tags: thermodynamics, glass

If we have a  room temperature glass bowl placed on a wet counter would the glass break more easily when hot water is poured in it, than if the counter had not been wet?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's enough information to even answer that.  The room humidity might even change the answer.

Comment: Would it matter if the counter is wet under any conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is in thermal equilibrium before the hot water is poured, it does not matter if the counter is wet or not. Thermal shock in glass containers arises because the thermal expansion of the material opens up small cracks in the surface of the glass. High temperature gradients (like the ones created by suddenly pouring hot/cold water) promote this kind of failure, which is likely to occur short after the liquid is poured not even allowing a proper heat exchange with the exterior.